# X509Chain.Build() succeeding for revoked certificate. C#

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, certificate-revocation

I create a certificate request like this:

```
certreq -new req.inf req-Revoked.req
certreq -submit -attrib "SAN:email=ttesting@Test.Domain&upn=1234567890@Test.Domain" -config Win2K8-64\Test-Win2K8-64-CA req-Revoked.req testerCert-Revoked.cer
certreq -accept testerCert-Revoked.cer
CertUtil -f -p testerCert -exportPFX -user My Testing.Tester.T.1234567890 testerCert-Revoked.pfx
CertUtil -delstore -user My Testing.Tester.T.1234567890
```

Then I revoke it, via:

```
CertUtil -revoke <SerialNumber_from_above_Cert>
```

I then execute this code:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate("testerCert-Revoked.pfx", "password"); // helper method loads the pfx from a file
X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;
chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

if (!chain.Build(certificate))
{
  errorBuffer.Append("Could not build X.509 certificate chain:\r\n");
  foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
  {
    errorBuffer.AppendFormat("  - {0}\r\n", status.StatusInformation);
  }
  throw new CryptographicException(errorBuffer.ToString());
}
```

chain.Build() always returns true. But since the certificate is revoked, it should be False! I've double-checked that the certificate is revoked, and that the serial number is listed in the Server Manager under revoked certificates. I've double-checked that the CURL distribution point urls match on the server and the certificate requests. (they're LDAP urls).  CertUtil sees the intermediate .cer file as revoked. But the C# code above doesn't.

This all worked before the original CA expired, and IT rebuilt my test machine with a new cert. I've regenerated the certs with the new CA, and every single unit tests works again, except the ones that deal with revocation. Expired certs work as expected, but not revoked certs.

I'm at a loss for what to do next to get this code working again, and would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: I've also published the CURL through Server Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was an application called Tumbleweed. It was installed on the server, and was intercepting all revocation requests. Disabling the Tumbleweed service fixed my problem entirely.

Charles.

Answer (score 0):

The chain is simply a list of the certificates, starting with the one you providing, all the way up to the root certificate.  It's built out of whatever certificates can be found -- even if they are out of date, invalid, or revoked.

What you're trying to do is validate the chain.  Use the chain.ChainStatus for that.

From the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain(v=vs.110).aspx):
The X509Chain object has a global error status called ChainStatus that should be used for certificate validation. The rules governing certificate validation are complex, and it is easy to oversimplify the validation logic by ignoring the error status of one or more of the elements involved. The global error status takes into consideration the status of each element in the chain.